# QLabel not responding to `setText()` at the time of calling

Tags: c++, qt

I am using the QT IDE to make a better looking version of my (once working) command line auto clicker.

Mind you, the clicking still works great... the functionality is not compromised.

However, the problem comes when 'updating' the text fields on the form itself.

In my code, you can see that pressing the 'Q' button, ends the loop. At this point, the text fields become updated (as they should be continuously during the loop). I'm really not sure why they aren't updating until I hit 'Q'. Is there any reason this isn't supposed to work as I think it should, or is there a way to fix it?

Thanks. See my code below. Mind you, I will only include the bits I believe are necessary. Upon request I can post more code.

**CODE.cpp**

```
bool running = 1;
float x = 1500;
float interval;
int breakCounter = 0;
float breakSeconds = 0;
int clicks = 0;

Sleep (3000);

while (running == 1)
{
    float breakChance = (rand()%650+1);
    if (breakChance == 100){
        breakCounter++;

        float breakTime = (rand()%180+1);
        breakTime = (breakTime + 60) * 1000;
        breakSeconds = breakSeconds + breakTime/1000;

        QString a = QString::number(breakCounter);
        QString b = QString::number(breakSeconds/60);
        QString c = QString::number(breakTime/1000);

        ui->label_6->setText(a);
        ui->label_7->setText(b + " mins");
        ui->label_8->setText(c);
        ui->label_9->setText("N/A");
        Sleep (breakTime);
    } else {
        float variance = (rand()%500+1);
        int flip = (rand()%2+1);
        if (flip == 1){
            interval = x + variance;
        } else {
            interval = x - variance;
        }

        QString a = QString::number(breakCounter);
        QString b = QString::number(breakSeconds/60);
        QString d = QString::number(interval);

        ui->label_6->setText(a);
        ui->label_7->setText(b + " mins");
        ui->label_8->setText("N/A");
        ui->label_9->setText(d);

        Sleep (interval);

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep (100);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        clicks++;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState( 'Q' ))
        {
            running = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**CODE.ui**

```
<item>
 <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
  <item>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Current break timer:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
  <item>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
    <property name="text">
     <string>N/A</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
 </layout>
</item>
<item>
 <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
  <item>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Next click time:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
  <item>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
    <property name="text">
     <string>N/A</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
 </layout>
</item>
```

Comment: It's because you're stuck in the loop until you press 'Q', then you're allowing Qt to run its update functions. Until you do that, you're hogging all processing time in your loop. I would look into using the QTimer and run your update at set intervals rather than Sleeping within the loop itself.

Comment: could you not call processEvents() to force a refresh? (not the safest way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt's paint messages happen when the application message pump is given a chance to run.  What you appear to have here is a loop that keeps your code on the stack and doesn't relinquish control back to the message pump.

If you want delays...the way to do that is with a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTimer.html).  Say how long you want it to be until your code runs next, return out of your code, and give the message pump a chance to run while time passes.

Comment: Upon research of a QTimer I stumbled across the usage of processEvents, as mentioned by user chris above, and it works out great! Thanks for pointing out that it needs a chance to process. I had no idea.

Comment: If `processEvents()` works for you and this is an isolated case and it gets you over a hump, then all right...but there are issues with that as a general approach.  Since your code is on the stack during the call, you run the risk of re-entrancy; arbitrary messages could be dispatched that call back into routines you're in the middle of running.  It also asks the question of when and what code makes these calls.  The better solution in Qt style is to avoid processEvents and have a "don't call Qt, let Qt call you" attitude about message pumping...

Comment: @JoshBeckwith I would not recommend using `processEvents`. It's very dangerous. For example your `Code` object could be deleted after the `processEvents` call which could cause major problems. Just cause it works now, doesn't mean it won't cause any problems in the future.

Comment: @JoshBeckwith I will add that using a sleep() based approach means that during the sleeping, you are blocking the UI thread from responding to events other than painting...so that messes even with things like resizing the window (for instance).  The events will pile up and then all be processed in your processEvents() call.  Another good reason to use QTimer and get your code off the stack while you wait...responding to the slot call and letting Qt pump messages in the meantime.

Comment: Since it was my first time looking at the QTimer family of commands and syntax, it was obviously hard to fully grasp how to correctly use it. I tried using a regular QTimer, I tried a OneShot timer, as well as a simple start/stop timer. However I tried to no success, which is why I went with the processEvents command.

Comment: @JoshBeckwith There's no limit to the number of StackOverflow questions you can ask.  *(Unless you ask enough bad ones and get a question ban, but that takes a while.  :-P)*  Learning how to use Signals and Slots correctly and QTimers is probably worth it to ask another question if you hit a wall in trying it out.